# safeTransferFrom does not transfer etherium to the target. ERC-721

Tags: solidity, web3js, openzeppelin

I create a contract with ERC-721 and I try to transfer the token with money. I am using web3.js and openzeppelin. So, The transaction is confirmed, but no money is sent to the target wallet.

**Here is the contract buy function;**

```
function buy(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
address buyer = msg.sender;

require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, _tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
approve(buyer, _tokenId);
safeTransferFrom(ownerOf(_tokenId), buyer, _tokenId); 
}
```

**And here is *web3.js* :**

```
const buy = (2,2) => {
//Token ID: 2
//Price: 2 ether
contract.methods.buy(2).send({ from: account, value: web3.utils.toWei(2, 'ether') })
}
```

**Here is transaction Response of Buy Function**

```
{
    "transactionHash": "0xb4267ac3da9a240dc007c118f710a0c9c1fab7d9eb1fab2097acacaec1ac56ee",
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "blockHash": "0xf6b8b8456cc3ac6103f03e747e9ca92ada3b68cc86fd408e6e9e03c07d5bcc55",
    "blockNumber": 208,
    "from": "0xefd8c34cf80828bd9d7b12256421b0d10d75fa86",
    "to": "0x112c6dcedb141d2da934696bf8d6cd460eef111e",
    "gasUsed": 83787,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 83787,
    "contractAddress": null,
    "status": true,
    "logsBloom": "0x04000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000020000000000000000000800000000000000000000000010000000000100000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000110000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000010000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000200000",
    "events": {
        "Approval": {
            "logIndex": 0,
            "transactionIndex": 0,
            "transactionHash": "0xb4267ac3da9a240dc007c118f710a0c9c1fab7d9eb1fab2097acacaec1ac56ee",
            "blockHash": "0xf6b8b8456cc3ac6103f03e747e9ca92ada3b68cc86fd408e6e9e03c07d5bcc55",
            "blockNumber": 208,
            "address": "0x112c6dCEDb141D2da934696BF8d6CD460EEf111e",
            "type": "mined",
            "id": "log_3514a43f",
            "returnValues": {
                "0": "0xf298d44e534E465727f8E6A02F0E95Fe0d360fbC",
                "1": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "2": "2",
                "owner": "0xf298d44e534E465727f8E6A02F0E95Fe0d360fbC",
                "approved": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "tokenId": "2"
            },
            "event": "Approval",
            "signature": "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
            "raw": {
                "data": "0x",
                "topics": [
                    "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000f298d44e534e465727f8e6a02f0e95fe0d360fbc",
                    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Transfer": {
            "logIndex": 1,
            "transactionIndex": 0,
            "transactionHash": "0xb4267ac3da9a240dc007c118f710a0c9c1fab7d9eb1fab2097acacaec1ac56ee",
            "blockHash": "0xf6b8b8456cc3ac6103f03e747e9ca92ada3b68cc86fd408e6e9e03c07d5bcc55",
            "blockNumber": 208,
            "address": "0x112c6dCEDb141D2da934696BF8d6CD460EEf111e",
            "type": "mined",
            "id": "log_95b82cfe",
            "returnValues": {
                "0": "0xf298d44e534E465727f8E6A02F0E95Fe0d360fbC",
                "1": "0xEFD8C34Cf80828BD9D7B12256421b0d10d75fA86",
                "2": "2",
                "from": "0xf298d44e534E465727f8E6A02F0E95Fe0d360fbC",
                "to": "0xEFD8C34Cf80828BD9D7B12256421b0d10d75fA86",
                "tokenId": "2"
            },
            "event": "Transfer",
            "signature": "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
            "raw": {
                "data": "0x",
                "topics": [
                    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000f298d44e534e465727f8e6a02f0e95fe0d360fbc",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000efd8c34cf80828bd9d7b12256421b0d10d75fa86",
                    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the transaction info as well (at least `data` and `value` fields)? Also, if you have the `ABI` that you're passing to the `contract`, please add the part that defines the `buy()` function in the JSON... I see an inconsistency between the one argument defined in Solidity (`buy(uint256 _tokenId)`) and passing two arguments in Javascript (`buy(tokenId, price)`) but I'm not sure whether that causes the issue.

Comment: @PetrHejda Thank you for your answer. I have added some details that you can see transaction response. And also I try to add my ABI but there is too much code :(

Comment: No need for the ABI anymore, the updated `web3.js` part is now self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my contract buy function like this;

```
function buy(uint256 _tokenId, address payable _owner, uint256 _amount) public payable {
    address payable buyer = msg.sender; 
    address payable owner = _owner;  //<-- *payable (important)
    
    _transfer(ownerOf(_tokenId), buyer, _tokenId);
      
    owner.transfer(_amount); //<--- this function send the amount to the token owner.

}
```

The problem was solved!
*Note: This is a simple contract. If you want to use , please be careful.*